# How do I selectively import few tables from a mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables in my dev database and I have take a mysqldump of all the tables.
I would like to re-create a different database only with 4 tables from the above mysqldump, how do I do that.

Note: I would like to skip data population for the 5th table, but would like to retain the schema definition for the table though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it in two steps:

1. Use --no-data option: `>mysqldump -no-data database_name`
2. Use --no-create-info and --tables options: `>mysqldump --no-create-info database_name --tables table1 table2 table3 table4`

[mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)